# GhostScript 'PDF to Image' makes blank image file

Tags: pdf, thumbnails, ghostscript

Now, I'm creating a program which is generating pdf thumbnails by using C# WinForm.
So I choose to use GhostScript to get PDF Thumbnail.
However, GhostScript create blank image from sometimes(some pdf files).
(only a parts of Pdf files are converted to Blank Image Files, other are correctly converted to Image file.)
This blank image files is same image size with pdf, but it is just white image.

And I found that these PDF files are showed a blank page in a short time when I open this files by PDF Reader.
So I expect these pdf files have some special option(like protection??) and GhostScript also need some special option to covert it correctly.

I'm using GhostScript.NET(https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com), and my code is below.

```
GhostscriptVersionInfo _lastInstalledVersion = null;
private GhostscriptRasterizer _rasterizer = null;
int dpi = 100;
string inputPdfPath = @"F:\pdf\155.pdf";
_lastInstalledVersion = GhostscriptVersionInfo.GetLastInstalledVersion(GhostscriptLicense.GPL |  GhostscriptLicense.AFPL, GhostscriptLicense.GPL);
_rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer();
_rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, _lastInstalledVersion, false);
Image img = _rasterizer.GetPage(dpi, dpi, 1);
_rasterizer.Close();
```

Please help me to solve this problem...

In addition, I tried to use Winapi CodePack, Magik.NET.
However, Winapi create PDF Icon, Magik.NET makes errors.(Both of them is worse than GhostScript.)

Comment: What does adobe acrobat say to your pdf files that appear blank? You can't expect us to guess if your pdfs are protected?

Comment: Or to put the question the other way: how do you know for sure that the pdfs aren't simply blank?

Comment: Try using Ghostscript from the command line directly, and look at the stdout backchannel, most likely your PDF file(s) are damaged in some way. It would be helpful to post a typical example, the fact that other consumers also don't like these files is indicative of the PDF file itself being a problem. You should also be able to get the backchannel from Ghostscript.NET but I cannot help you with that, as its not part of Ghostscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you KenS!
It probably caused by GhostScript.NET.
I tried to use original GhostScript and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting blank images for PDF files that were recently opened/viewed with PDF Reader then the most probable issue is that these files are simply blocked by PDF Reader application. And Ghostscript is failing silently while trying to read / access these PDF files and generating blank images then.

I would suggest to avoid opening/reading these PDF files with PDF Reader software to make sure that they are exclusively used by Ghostrscript only.